# Python installation along with django framework

Tags: python, django, installation

The first problem we are facing is after installing python, the python path can't be set properly.Also please guide me the steps for installing python along with Django.

Comment: which os? you are using?

Comment: Have you even searched? The official docs offer many options to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Question is which OS?

if **Linux,**

Python version 2.7 is pre-installed, simply activate pip by typing `sudo easy_install pip` and then you can install django by typing `pip install django`.

However i will recommend using virtualenv before installing libraries. Know more about virtualenv here https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

The same goes for Mac as well.

If **Windows**

Install python version you need from the exe/msi file, available at the official website. Once installed successfully, add the python path and the script path to the env variables in the my Computer properties. Usually that is `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;` but this may differ depending on the location you installed python. Once done you can use pip like you were using in linux and do `pip install django` and you are good to go.

Let me know if you face any other difficulties.

Comment: how to do for windows 10 because the path of python after installing it is automatically taking as c:/user/user1/Appdata/local/programs/python 3.1.2. Can I set this path in the environmental variable?

Comment: Are you sure about the path, I hv never used windows 10? If yes you can add that in env variables

Comment: yes I am sure because while installing of python latest version that path is automatically tacking.

Comment: Please go ahead add that path in the env and test

Comment: no by adding it in env path still it is not taking that path

Comment: now I tried with python 2.7 version and I installed Django also but the server starting code "/> c:/python27/python manage.py runserver" is not working.

Comment: please do the same. add python2.7 path to env variables and directly execute python manage.py runserver. unlike linux windows python will not directly execute with full path